# Gnuplot - Y Axis further away from screen

Tags: graph, label, gnuplot

I have the following problem: My Graph in gnuplot looks good, except that the label on the y axis is overlaid by the y-tics. Or the other way around. Since the label is already on the edge of the figure, I would need the y-axis be further "inwards".

I attached my "problem". Please not that I can not change the font size of neither the label nor the tics. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJQkW.png

Comment: Besides the solution posted by kebs, you could also set the larger font for the whole terminal with `set terminal ... font ',20'`, in which case the automatic spacing should work better. But this is only a guess, because you don't show any code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't post any code, I would advice to make the left margin bigger, then edit the labels position. See `help margin` and `help ylabel` from an interactive session, or check the pdf manual.

For example:

```
set lmargin 10
set ylabel offset -3,0
```

You will probably need to search and try adequate values. Please note that the default units are "characters" (width or height).

Also note that the results can be terminal-dependent.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much good sir! It has to be 'set lmargin at screen', but you pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: The `at screen` is optional, see p. 125 of pdf manual (version 4.6) but you can indeed specify it.